# Perl graph garbage collection usage

Tags: perl, garbage-collection, graph

I have built a tiny application in Perl that displays a graph over time. It graphs garbage collection usage over time.  I use gnuplot to display the actual graph.

This works fine if the time period is short, like a few hours. However, as the time increases (say a few days), the graph becomes difficult to read as the information gets crammed. Note that there is a tool called gcviewer which performs a similar function, it works by allowing you to choose the percentage of the graph.

http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html

Ideally I would like to take this further by adding the ability to "move" within the graph.

I am not a developer but am good at scripting, so if there is some module in Perl which would provide this functionality it would be excellent!  However, if it cannot be done in Perl, I am not averse to learning a new technology.

Inputs are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) Profiler, as it allows the GC view to be adjusted accordingly. You might also look at [JFreeChart](http://netbeans.org/); the JWS [Demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp)'s `Memory Usage` tab does something similar.